# Cannot start visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Am using visual studio 2010 - enterprise edition

when i try to start my visual studio it gives the error "Cannot load file or assembly : presentationcore "

I found this on the event log too

```
.NET Runtime Optimization Service (clr_optimization_v4.0.30319_32) - 1>Failed to compile: PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 . Error code = 0x80070002
```

any help will be grate full

Comment: Are you trying to open a specific project or just open visual studio from the start menu? Did you try to reboot see if that fixes it?

Comment: I remember having a similar problem; I solved it by running all windows updates and then rebooting my computer.

Comment: The error code means "file not found".  Which is what Visual Studio already told you.  Your .NET 4.0 install is borken, you'll have to re-install it.

Comment: Its when starting visual studio by clicking denenv.exe or any .sln file

Comment: Solved it by reinstalling .net framework